# Merging Java Applications resources

Tags: java, maven

I have two java applications with different "config.yml" files, i use "Maven shade plugin" but i need to merge config files as well, how can i do this?

Structure of first application:

```
src/main
　|-- java
　|　　|-- Code1
　|
　|-- resources
　　　　|-- config.yml
　　　　|-- plugin.yml
```

Structure of second application:

```
 src/main
　|-- java
　|　　|-- Code2
　|
　|-- resources
　　　　|-- config.yml
　　　　|-- lang.yml
```

What I expect to see:

```
 src/main
　|-- java
　|　　|-- Code1
　|　　|-- Code2
　|
　|-- resources
　　　　|-- config.yml (Merged)
　　　　|-- lang.yml
　　　　|-- plugin.yml
```

My Maven build configuration (which does everything i need, except merging config.yml):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I do not know of any plugin capable of merging config files. And I am also not sure of how this would be done in a portable way. How would a maven plugin know, how to solve merge conflicts if there are any? You might need to write your own plugin for this specific use case.

Comment: @JohannesH. Thx for help <3